# Impossible to send mail with Oracle Linux

Tags: linux, email, configuration, sendmail, oracle-linux

I just installed `sendmail` on Oracle Linux and with `mutt` I would like to send an e-mail. In the local system I have the username `user1`; in the ISP mail account I have the address `mailaddress@domain.com`. I tried to send an e-mail to myself, so the sender and recipient are the same address.

My ISP requires simple authentication on SMTP server in order to send mails, so I followed [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E41138/html/ch16s06.html) guide. **Important**: I left the word `dml` at the end of every added line.

The `/var/log/maillog` is the following:

```
Jul 19 13:15:01 OracleLinux sendmail[2620]: unable to qualify my own domain name (OracleLinux) -- using short name
Jul 19 13:15:01 OracleLinux sendmail[2620]: u6JBE1TW002620: Authentication-Warning: OracleLinux: user1 set sender to mailaddress@domain.com using -f
Jul 19 13:15:01 OracleLinux sendmail[2620]: u6JBE1TW002620: from=mailaddress@domain.com, size=341, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<20160719111301.GA2616@OracleLinux>, relay=user1@localhost
Jul 19 13:15:01 OracleLinux sendmail[2642]: u6JBF1Vn002642: from=<mailaddress@domain.com>, size=573, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<20160719111301.GA2616@OracleLinux>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Jul 19 13:15:01 OracleLinux sendmail[2620]: u6JBE1TW002620: to=mailaddress@domain.com, ctladdr=mailaddress@domain.com (1000/1000), delay=00:01:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30341, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (u6JBF1Vn002642 Message accepted for delivery)
Jul 19 13:15:01 OracleLinux sendmail[2644]: u6JBF1Vn002642: to=<mailaddress@domain.com>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=120573, relay=remote.smtp.com [<remote.smtp.com IP>], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Jul 19 13:15:01 OracleLinux sendmail[2644]: u6JBF1Vn002642: u6JBF1Vn002644: DSN: Service unavailable
Jul 19 13:15:01 OracleLinux sendmail[2644]: u6JBF1Vn002644: to=<mailaddress@domain.com>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=31770, relay=remote.smtp.com, dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Jul 19 13:15:02 OracleLinux sendmail[2644]: u6JBF1Vn002644: u6JBF1Vo002644: return to sender: Service unavailable
Jul 19 13:15:02 OracleLinux sendmail[2644]: u6JBF1Vo002644: to=root, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=32794, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

In the error mail sent locally to `root`, the following error is showed:

```
530 authentication required for mail submission
```

But in the guide I linked I created a `.db` file with my username and password related to ISP (and I successfully use them with a GUI e-mail client).
What can be done with `sendmail` when using and external SMTP server? What's wrong with this configuration?

Comment: Most examples of the authinfo file have something like `AuthInfo:remote.smtp.com: "U:user1" "I:userforisp" "P:passwordforisp"`.

Comment: @meuh I tried writing the authinfo file as you suggested and thanks. But I obtained the same error and `maillog` looks very similar, if not equal, to the post.

Comment: The first problem may occur because your server has a short name that does not include a domain name, i.e. it is not a FQN.-- You may check an answer in [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/506462/how-to-fix-unable-to-qualify-my-own-domain-name-myhost-using-short-name) and in [askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436260/sm-msp-queue-says-unable-to-qualify-my-own-domain-name-xxx-using-short-nam)